# Remove string in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following entry in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule  ^blogs$ ?name=data&case=gview&group_id=31%1 [L]
```

What I do is, I *redirect* `blogs` to `?name=data&case=gview&group_id=31`

Now what happens is, all my urls are now `blogs?id=1` etc, but I need them to stay just `?id=1`

How can I remove the `blogs` from rest of the urls?

This what I came up with, but it doesn't work:

```
RewriteRule ^blogs?(.*)$ /$1 [L]
```

*EDIT* I might be explaining it wrong. I need to change the actual url display of the links. Is that actually possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the answer is pretty much: *It can't be done*. I just went over my code, added `/` before main urls and all is working as intended.

Thank you both for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure... but is that what you're looking for ?

```
RewriteRule  ^/?$ /blogs [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with just adding a `R` to your original rule?

```
RewriteRule  ^blogs$ ?name=data&case=gview&group_id=31%1 [L,R=301]
```